# Unable to connect to pymqi windows 64bit - Connection broken

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am getting the below error while connecting to IBM MQ using library pymqi.

Its a clustered MQ channel

```
AMQ6235: Directory 'U:' missing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postToQueue.py", line 425, in <module>
    qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymqi\__init__.py", line 2534, in connect
    qmgr = QueueManager(queue_manager)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymqi\__init__.py", line 1319, in __init__
    self.connect(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymqi\__init__.py", line 1345, in connect
    raise MQMIError(rv[1], rv[2])
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2009: FAILED: MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN
```

Please see my code below.

```
queue_manager = 'quename here'
channel = 'channel name here'
host = 'host-name here'
port = '2333'
queue_name = 'queue name here'
conn_info = '%s(%s)' % (host, port)
print(conn_info)
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)
queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)
queue.put(message)
print("message sent")
queue.close()
qmgr.disconnect()
message = 'my message here'
```

Getting error at the line below

```
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206215/discussion-on-question-by-machiraju-alekhya-unable-to-connect-to-pymqi-windows-6).

Comment: @SamuelLiew I can not access chat so will stop helping this years for now.

Comment: Can we change the installation data path from Homdriver and Homepath as my Homedriver and path are not accessible when using client VPN . How can i do that which installation?